# Pasting Split Data From Column B into Columns D & E

Tags: vba, excel, split

In column B there is the 5 character item code + the item description.
I managed to make a macro that copy/pastes the 5 character item codes from column B into column D and the item descriptions into column E.

Example:

```
          Column B              Column C  Column D     Column E
XX787 DO BOLOGNESE 2X2.28KG FR   <other>    XX787    DO BOLOGNESE 2X2.28KG FR
```

I am facing the following issues:

- About 1% of the item codes are not 5 characters but 8 characters, for example
- This percentage that exists out of 8 characters exists of numbers and starts with 0

As you can see, the last 2 are examples of item codes that have a different format, and even though there is only a small amount of them, they have to be taken into account of course.

So with my current coding, the following issues arise:

[image: Hier een foto]

I think the macro should do the following to make this work properly:

For item codes in column D: Copy/paste all the characters BEFORE the first space from column B
For item descriptions in column E: Copy/paste all the characters AFTER the first space

The code I am currently running for this is the following:

```
Sub Seperate_Item_Code_And_Description_Code()
    'Copy/paste the item codes and descriptions from column B to column D and E seperately

    Range("B12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D12"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this coded and conditional text-to-columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewtrqw()
    Dim s As Long, a As Long, aVALs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        aVALs = .Range(.Cells(12, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim Preserve aVALs(LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1), 1 To 2)
        For a = LBound(aVALs, 1) To UBound(aVALs, 1)
            s = InStr(1, aVALs(a, 1), Chr(32))
            aVALs(a, 2) = Mid(aVALs(a, 1), s + 1)
            aVALs(a, 1) = Left(aVALs(a, 1), s - 1)
        Next a
        .Cells(12, "D").Resize(UBound(aVALs, 1), UBound(aVALs, 2)) = aVALs
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following error: subscription out of range                                                            THANKS A LOT for your fast help btw

Comment: Did you change the name of the worksheet to be processed?

Comment: Yes, I did. Why? :)

Comment: Would it be possible to add you on skype? I need some further help with automating Vlookuo using VBA macro's. I dont wanna disppoint my boss or i might get fired, even though he is a very good guy.. I would be willing to pay even.. Via paypal or bank idk... Sounds dramatic but this job is importsnt and i dont wanna lose it

Comment: I cannot commit to something like that at this time. I would suggest you post your requirements in [StackOverflow Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab).

Comment: I'm guessing that there is no space in the entry that threw that error.